# How is a blob column annotated in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, annotations, blob

How is a blob column annotated in Hibernate?
So far I have a class that has:

```
@Column( name = "FILEIMAGE" )
private byte[ ] fileimage ;
//
public byte[ ] getFileimage ( ) { return this.fileimage ; }
public void setFilename ( String filename ) { this.filename = filename ; }
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

@Lob should do the trick for blob and clob (use String as type)

```
@Column( name = "FILEIMAGE" )
@Lob(type = LobType.BLOB)
private byte[] fileimage;
```

Comment: dependent on the hibernate version, the Lob annotation could have no type parameter. 

quote from [here](https://www.hibernate.org/398.html):

@Lob no longer has attributes, the lob type (CLOB, BLOB) is guessed. If the underlying type is a String or an array of character then CLOB are used. Othersise BLOB are used.

Comment: thanks guys for your quick answers. is the sequence important?
@Column( name = "FILEIMAGE" , length = 1048576 ) @Lob 
private byte[ ] fileimage ;

Comment: I have not a parameters for @Lob in hibernate 5.1.

Answer (score 3):

I used hibernate 4 in JBoss 7 and Java 7, and found out the `BLOB` column in my table doesn't work like what I have for hibernate 2. Fortunately, I solved it by reading other people solutions.
My solution:

1. Table in db, the column still defined in BLOB; change the hibernate mapping from `type="blob"` to `type="binary"`
2. In Java getter/setter, using `byte[]` instead of `BLOB` (`javax.sql`)
3. Change in the Java code which get and set this column properly. If involving InputStram, use `byte[]` to read/write to `BLOB` column; If reading from DB by using `java.sql.ResultSet`, make sure use getBytes() instead of `getBlob()` method.