# Lucene JDBC Directory

Tags: java, lucene

I am using Lucene 3.5.0 to do some basic search stuff on my website. I want to store the index in a JDBC Directory in my Mysql Database. I was going to use the Compass Project to do this, but with some more research and actually trying the code I have found that Compass is a dead project and it no longer is compatible with the current version of Lucene.

Is there another option to store my index in a JDBC Directory? Is there a reason Lucene does not offer this native? Is storing on the HDD a better option for some reason?

Comment: What's a JDBC directory? Why do you want it in a DB?

Comment: JDBC Directory is the method Compass uses to create a table in the database to store the index. Honestly, I want to approach that because it seems easier and other than the fact that I can't get it working, it seems that the best place to store an indexed database is in the database itself. I can be convinced otherwise though if a directory is a better option.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood; thanks. Not sure how it'd be easier, though. Also, DB indices and operations seem like they'd be tuned for a different type of problem.

Comment: The JDBCDirectory implementation from Compass project still works very well (in modern Java). Implemented for a new service and was impressed by the options. Take care with the default locking implementation that is done at the database layer though. It seems to have myriad issues with abandoned locks and system inaccessibility on update as a result. However, by implementing the one-writer strategy (lock it yourself) is an option by configuration and solves issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Can_I_store_the_Lucene_index_in_a_relational_database.3F):

Lucene does not support that functionality out of the box, but several people have implemented [JdbcDirectory's](https://www.google.com/search?q=jdbcdirectory%20lucene). The reports we have seen so far indicate that performance with such implementations is not great, but it is doable.

Another approach would be to store the index in the database as a BLOB, this could be useful if you have multiple nodes running your application. If you add a timestamp to the BLOB each node could check whether the index has been updated and recreate the index file from the DB.

Comment: Could I bother you for an example of how to store an index as a BLOB? I've never done that before and have no idea how to implement it from Lucene.

Comment: @ryandlf See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939673/how-is-a-blob-column-annotated-in-hibernate with hibernate you would just read the file and store its contents in the byte array.

Comment: Ok, not sure it would be as easy as that but i'll look into it. Lucene creates a number of different files each time it indexes the database.

Comment: ya that's not very clear which of those files should be stored

Comment: Note that "storing the index in the database as a BLOB" would not have any direct file-system interactions. Indeed this is the point. File-systems have poor/buggy locking for update-capable indexes. Granted, any DB will have a FS impl thereof but the indexes themselves would be maintained by the [JDBCDirectory] code through the DB and with associated (much better) DB record-locking such that each BLOB is a record with a primary-key. See Compass project (albeit dated and not compatible with Lucene 4.x).

Comment: FYI - realized performance of implementation as measured in 3-digit milliseconds per query can be found at Private Speak - a new service: https://www.privatespeak.com

Answer (score 0):

There are three questions here, which, violating the question/answer format of the forum, I will try to answer as they are related:

Q: "Is there another option to store my index in a JDBC Directory [that is compatible with Lucene 4.x]?"

A: "Google search... but no, not in widespread use. Most devs have moved to ElasticSearch, which bundles many aspects together into a much larger package. Sadly, JDBC is a dying thing as many K/V databases are taking hold. Interestingly enough, from file-systems to non-transactionally supported K/V databases ... none of these solutions are actually viable for a distributed updatable index due to unreliable operating-system file-locking or lack of ACID guarantees.

Q: "Is there a reason Lucene does not offer this native?"

A: "Ask the Lucene contributors but ... in reading their documentation, again, they have moved onto more comprehensive and commercial solutions built ontop of ElasticSearch, REST APIs and generally language-neutral implementations (versus Lucene being the underlying Java-native implementation going back decades).

Q: "Is storing on the HDD a better option for some reason?"

A: "Not recommended generally due to unreliable OS file-locking for updatable indexes and non-distribution support (envision multiple processes and nodes trying to concurrently update the same index file/s). Even AWS S3 has been shown as not viable for this purpose due to lack of locking and need to effectively delete and re-create S3 objects to effectively accomplish the task.