# Hibernate Search: persisting Lucene index into database

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-search

I am developing a Spring boot application which is using spring data JPA as a persistence layer. I would like to enable a full text search with [hibernate search](http://hibernate.org/search/), but because of some constraints i would like to persist the Lucene index into the database (instead of a file).

I have went through the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-configuration) but was unable to find an example of persisting the index into a database. Also from reading it i understood that this is possible but i don't know where to start.

**How should the configuration look like?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's definitely not possible out of the box.

However, if you're willing to implement a solution yourself, you can plug it into Hibernate Search.

I've never done it, but I can offer some pointers.

You will need:

- A custom implementation of `org.apache.lucene.store.Directory`: this is the adapter between Lucene and your storage solution (in your case, the database). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967664/lucene-jdbc-directory); that's about a very old version of Lucene, but at least it's a starting point.
- A custom implementation of `org.hibernate.search.store.DirectoryProvider`: this is the component that configures and creates the `Directory` on startup.
- Some configuration to tell Hibernate Search to use your `DirectoryProvider`. See [this section of the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-configuration-directory)

This should also be possible in [Hibernate Search 6](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.0/), though the directory provider interface is different: `org.hibernate.search.backend.lucene.lowlevel.directory.spi.DirectoryProvider`.