# store BLOB inside DB with playframework 1.2.4

Tags: jpa, playframework, blob, playframework-1.x

I know that by default plays JPA implementation uses DB to store references to BLOBs stored in file system, and I haven't found, by this far, any way to switch this behaviour. - Is it possible somehow? If yes, how?

My specyfic use case requires storing content of large text files inside DB to make access to them as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use the `@javax.persistence.Lob` annotation.

There was a [bug raised](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/987) that the documentation does not cover the use case of saving data to a DB instead of a filesystem. The resolution to the bug was to point the asker to the following source code...

https://gist.github.com/1275419

Answer (score 0):

I based my solution for images on this gist and it works pretty well.

https://gist.github.com/660937

You can also store bytes if you need, look at this other SO question.

[How is a blob column annotated in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939673/how-is-a-blob-column-annotated-in-hibernate)

Hope it helps.