# JPA entity byte[] mapped to bytea PostgreSQL always null

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql, jpa, bytea

I am having a java class with one of its attribute:

```
private byte[] file;
```

When I upload a image it stores itself in my PostgreSQL database as `bytea` data (and other attributes stores themselves successfully as well). When I retrieve my entity from DB, everything is retrieved perfectly except the file `byte[]` is always null (byte data seems not to be retrieved at all).

Any ideas?

Edit: I tried @Lob annotation - did not help.

Comment: try to use `@Lob` annotation, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939673/how-is-a-blob-column-annotated-in-hibernate

Comment: I did try that even before posting this (I should've mention it) and it did not solve the issue, thanks for suggestion though.

Comment: Using LAZY loading?

Comment: I completely changed the approach in the end and I can't remember how it was, sorry. On one hand it would explain it I guess, on the other hand, it would be very dumb from me. :D

Comment: Well not necessarily dumb. I had the same problem so that is why interested. Some pg 9.5 version or so, could not get LAZY work. But now with v11 @Lob defaults nicely to OID tyep column and also LAZY works.

Comment: Oh, did not know that, thanks for info. And you are right it is not dumb I poorly explained myself, it would be dumb from me not to test EAGER. :)